# Why cute things make us want to touch it?

Tags: cognitive-psychology

Why when we see a cute cat or dog, we immedietly want to make physical contact with it (touch, hug, smell, etc.)? Does brain percives cute things somehow like food? Or maybe it triggers parent-child reaction?

Comment: Interesting to see how folks who don't have much cognition left (Alzheimer's, dementia) still love to wheeled out to hear the birds sing. Another interesting one are fish in a "Sea World"...it seems a regular occurrence for children to literally touch the "wall" or glass between themselves and say a dolphin that has swum to them to apparently "take a look." Seems a little dangerous and yet somehow maybe there is an ancient memory between human and nature that remains "engineered" into our very being...no matter the state of our mind.

Comment: Not sure why there are so many close votes given articles like this one: http://www.cell.com/trends/cognitive-sciences/abstract/S1364-6613(16)30042-0

Comment: @mrt Thank you for the article. If you would change this comment into answer I will accept it.

Comment: @mrt Probably because it lacks initial research. Many currently active users expect better phrased questions.

Comment: if so, this is similar with case when people looks trypophobia images, then he would scared with the disease. People "feels" what infront of them